# Stopping CLLocationManager?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to ask for advice on stopping a CLLocationManager -startUpdatingLocation. Currently I am considering two methods, but I am unsure which to use and would like to get an idea how other folks do this:

**Method_001:**

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self performSelector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocation:) withObject:@"TimedOut" afterDelay:30];
```

- Potentially wastes battery life as always runs for 30secs
- If network is slow might not get an accurate location in time
- Feels quite a tidy way to implement the timeout.

**Method_002:**

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then inside: `-locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` add:

```
static int timeOut = 0;
timeOut++;

// Other code that checks for and stops
// when a suitable result, accuracy, age etc is found.

if(timeOut >= 4) {
    [[self locationManager] stopUpdatingLocation];
    timeOut = 0;
    return;
}
```

- Might not resolve an accurate location in 4 (or less) attempts.
- 4 results might not be returned for CLLocationManager and we never timeout.
- Better on battery life as we stop immediately on a good result.

Just curious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I think I prefer the first one. I don't know if we can be sure about how often the `didUdpateToLocation:` method gets called. I think the time out is more reliable.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, currently I am using method_002, but noticed that sometimes there is not a 4th call to the delegate. This seems to happen if the first return is particularly accurate. Likewise if you set 3 as a timeout particularly difficult situations (bad cell coverage) don't resolve accurately to a usable location.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I think the CLLocationManager handles these cases internally.  Just configure it thus:

```
locManager.desiredAccuracy = 2000.0f;   // 2 kilometers - hope for accuracy within 2 km.
locManager.distanceFilter  = 1000.0f;   // one kilometer - move this far to get another update
```

and then in the callback  didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
 if you have a positive signbit,

```
 [locManager stopUpdatingLocation];  // stop GPS
```

EDIT: add signbit

```
if (signbit(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy)) {
        // Negative accuracy means an invalid or unavailable measurement, so punt.
} else {
        // this is a usable measurement.
    }
```

Comment: does the CLLocationManager respond to the selector 'disable'?

Comment: @atreat - good catch - that was a custom wrapper method in my code.  I've updated to use the correct method call.

Comment: what do you mean by "if you have a positive signbit,"

Comment: Does anyone have any evidence that CLLocationManager can ever return a CLLocation with negative horizontalAccuracy? Documentation for horizontalAccuracy states: "A negative value indicates that the latitude and longitude are invalid." So CLLocationManager should never return a CLLocation with such accuracy because it should never return a CLLocation with an invalid latitude or longitude... thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Why not to combine both approaches and give a third (i the best result didn't improve in some amount of time)

I wrote a GIT repo on this, which you are free to use
https://github.com/xelvenone/M6GPSLocationManager

- If the result accuracy is better than acceptableAccuracy, we are done
- If we get an update on occuracy, we wait maximumWaitTimeForBetterResult to get a better one, - If this doesn't happen, we are done and take the best one
- If we are constantly getting updates, which exceed maximumAttempts, we take th best one (probably we are moving anyway)
- If we don't get any other update in 30 sec, we are done (there won't be probably any other update)

Code

```
- (void)scopeToCurrentLocationWithAcceptableAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)acceptableAccuracy
                  maximumWaitTimeForBetterResult:(NSTimeInterval)maximumWaitTimeForBetterResult
                                 maximumAttempts:(NSInteger)maximumAttempts
                                    onCompletion:(M6GPSLocationManagerCompletion)completion;
```